# jquery add numeric class to an element based on current class of another element

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass, jquery-traversing

I have the following HTML

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>etc...</li>
</ul>
```

And the following jquery function I am using to append "buttons" for traversing "up" or "down" the list, while only "showing" the current item:

```
$('#tabs li').first().attr('class', 'current');

$('#tabs li').each(function(i) {
    i = i + 1;

$(this).attr('id', 'tab-' + i);

if(i !== $('#tabs li').size()) {
    $(this).append('<a class="tabPagination next floor-up" rel="tab-' + (i + 1) + '" href="/keyplate/' + (i + 1) + '">Up</a>');
    }
    if(i !== 1) {
        $(this).append('<a class="tabPagination next floor-down" rel="tab-' + (i - 1) + '" href="/keyplate/' + (i - 1) + '">Down</a>');
    }                
});            

$('#tabs li[class!="current"]').hide();

$(document).on("click", "a.tabPagination", function(){
    $('.current').removeAttr('class');
    $('#tabs li[class!="current"]').hide();    
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show(); 

});
```

I have another div:

```
<div id="tower"></div>
```

What I need to do is add a class to the #tower div, based on the currently selected #tab item. So for example if we are on #tab li = 2, then #tower div would get class="active_level_2".  In other words, take the value of 'current' #tab list item and use that to create "active_level_#".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the attribute `rel` and split it to get the last number to use for the `active_level_` class. We can also pull `$(this)` into a variable now since its being used more than once.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/QPaNG/)

```
$(document).on("click", "a.tabPagination", function(){
    var tab = $(this);
    $('.current').removeAttr('class');
    $('#tabs li[class!="current"]').hide();    
    $('#' + tab.attr('rel')).show(); 
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        $('#tower').removeClass('active-level-' + i);
    $('#tower').addClass('active_level_' + tab.attr('rel').split('-')[1]);
});
```

`tab.attr('rel').split('-')[1]` will get the tab's `rel` attribute, split the string into two at the `-` character using `split()` and get the second part to return the number we want.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks Daniel. I'm having some trouble with implementing this. It seems that instead of assigning #tower the current class, it's assigning the next class above that. Also, when you go "down" a level it's not removing and reassigning the next appropriate class.  To give you a better idea, in practice, what I'm trying to do is mimic the functionality seen [here](http://www.stationsquare.ca/floorplans/).

Comment: So as you can see in the fiddle, the only problem is actually changing the class again when you loop back "down" through the #tabs items. How do I over-write the class?

Comment: That's absolutely fantastic. Thank you so much!